# python mysql configuration problem

Tags: python, mysql, django, macos

I'm trying to make django work on snow leopard. So far I've installed mysql 64 bit installed python 2.7 64 bit and installed django 1.2.1. Now I'm trying to install mysql-python-1.2.3; at the beginning I had problems because I hadn't installed the setup tool, having done that when try to install it by executing these command

```
python setup.py build

python setup.py install
```

here's what I got

```
running build

running build_py

creating build/lib.macosx-10.5-fat3-2.7

error: could not create 'build/lib.macosx-10.5-fat3-2.7': Permission denied
```

Any idea?

Am I doing something wrong?

Thanks

Mauro

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use `sudo`

```
sudo setup.py build
sudo setup.py install
```

You might just want to use sqlite.

Comment: I'd also say that using Macports (http://www.macports.org/) is the easier way to get these packages on OS X (and update them over time).

Answer (score 0):

At the risk of pointing out the obvious, you do not have permission to write to the `build` directory.  Check and change the directory permissions (with the `chmod` command) or do the setup as an admin user.

Comment: thanks, but where in the os the build directory will be written?